# GRUB Issues Acer Aspire v5-513

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, bootloader

OK, this laptop is pissing me off.
I did a dual-boot install of Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 13.04.  I've done this many times on other systems, and never had a problem.  I am now.
The installation went fine, no errors at all, and I rebooted the laptop, ready to enjoy my new installation.  It didn't happen.  It didn't even bring up GRUB, just went right into Windows.  I rebooted into the live DVD and ran grub-install and update-grub, which both succeded with no warnings.  I rebooted...still no GRUB, so I updated the BIOS and tried again.  Still nothing.  I'm stumped and have no idea what to do.
The BIOS isn't a SecureBoot BIOS, and I honestly have no further idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hit <kbd>F12</kbd> over and over again until it takes you to a "special" boot menu. There, it will allow you to select what partition\drive to boot into. I have the same problem. The issue is that new machines skip over all boot selectors for some reason and just go straight to Windows to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on windows 7. Once in that, go to "add new entry" and select the "linux/bsd" tab and select type as "grub2" and click on "add entry". Save the settings and reboot. You should see grub option in the windows 7 bootloader now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just re-install grub from live installer unless you mount partition with install first. And you can only run the update from inside you install either after you have booted or from a chroot into your install.

How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7 bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Often easier just to use Boot-Repair.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can repair many boot issues with this or 'Create BootInfo' report (Other Options) & post the link it creates, so we can see your exact configuration and diagnose advanced problems.
LighterWeight (Lubuntu based) Boot-RepairCD

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/